# Snapping windows in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, gnome, unity

Is there a way in which I can prevent Ubuntu 20.04's windows from going to locations Ubuntu seems to want? I'd prefer to set the window locations for my apps to go where I want them to go.

I would like 1) my word processor to hug the left side of my laptop's screen from top to bottom, 2) my browser to hug he right side of the screen (top to bottom), and my e-mail app to stretch from left side across the wp onto my browser, but to NOT to hug the right side of the screen, and NOT extend to the bottom of the screen.

I've worked extensively over the past 30 years with Mac, MS Windows and Ubuntu 16 and 18 for the past 5 years, but I need to reset Ubuntu daily. Ubuntu 20.04 allows me even LESS freedom than previous versions. Both Mac and Windows allow me to set my screen the way I want. Is there a way I can get Ubuntu 20.04 LTS to do the same?

Comment: You can try Xubuntu or Ubuntu MATE instead. They have traditional desktop interfaces, which support snapping windows out of the box.

Comment: It depends on the window manager you use, not on Ubuntu itself. For example in Compiz there is a lot of configuration possibilities regarding windows placement. They are so extensive that I never investigated them in detail ;), as I don't care about Ubuntu placing windows at random positions (Windows does the same). But I'm positively sure that what you want is absolutely possible to configure in Compiz.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the GNOME extension `Auto Move Windows`

[image]
After installation you can configure how the extension works with your applications.

[image]

For it to work effectively you can select which applications to start by selecting
`Startup Applications Preferences`.

Comment: Hm... this is probably not what OP wants - the description on your screenshot says that the extension assigns windows to different workspaces. The OP wanted the windows to have specific, static **position** on the screen and not to be placed in specific workspace.

Comment: that can also be achieved with `Put Windows` extension - the two combined perhaps. GNOME extension [Put Windows](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/39/put-windows/). Also [ShellTile](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/657/shelltile/) could be considered.